# How to search data on created at less than in thinking sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Using `thinking_sphinx` to fetch data from records. It working fine but facing an issue that not find any to get records on date comparison like created_at greater than or less than. I check their official documentation also [Thinking Sphinx](https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v4/)

Is thinking sphinx provide that way? If yes then can we do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but it's not entirely obvious.

What you'll need to do is add an extra column in the SELECT clause, and then filter by that. Something along the lines of:

```
Model.search "pancakes",
  :select => "*, IF(created_at > #{1.year.ago.to_i}, 1, 0) AS time_match",
  :with   => {:time_match => 1}
```

You will need to have `created_at` as an attribute in your index file for this to work.